# Starting the app on device boot is not working well

Tags: android

I've used BroadcastReceiver to auto-start the app as soon as device boot is completed. But it is not working. While tested with cmd (adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -p com.capitaleyejobschedulers.com.jobschedulers), the log is shown only if the app is in the foreground. If it is minimized or swipe out from the app list (ie. app not running), it doesn't work.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
    mReceiver = new BootCompletedIntentReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.e("bootDeviceValue", " zzz");
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try{
        if(mReceiver!=null)
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

**Update 1:**

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.e("bootDeviceValue", " aaaaa");
    }
}
```

YourActivityRunOnStartup class

```
public class YourActivityRunOnStartup extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Log.e("bootDeviceValue", " bbbbb");
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zzzz.com.autorunonboot">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:name=".YourActivityRunOnStartup"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: A boot Receiver must be statically registered in the manifest, not dynamically registered on a `Context`.

Comment: hello @MikeM. PLease have a look at update 1 above in the question. It still is not working. What should I do in MainActivity to make it work?

Comment: Remove the `android:permission` attribute from the `<receiver>` element. Make sure you run your app at least once after installation to bring it out of the _stopped_ state; otherwise that Receiver won't run (since Android 3.1). Everything else looks good, but I would mention that some devices restrict apps from starting at boot by default, so beware of that, if you're testing on an actual device.

Comment: thank you so much after removing the permission in <receiver>, it worked.

Comment: Ah, good. No problem. Just to explain a little: the `permission` attribute on a `<receiver>` specifies the permission that the _sender_ of the broadcast must hold. The system component sending that broadcast might not necessarily have that permission, and so it would not be delivered to your Receiver. Just FYI. Glad you got it working. Cheers!